# IOS launch image sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

The [ios App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) states the following launch image sizes for iPad apps:

`1024x748px and 2048x1496px`.

Yet in XCode, I am given the following sizes for ipad portrait launch images in the tooltip:

`1024x768px and 2048x1536px`.

Which should I follow?

**note**:

the [ios human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) state:

`For iPad launch images, do not include the status bar region`.

I am confused as to which dimensions I should be following.

Answer (score 66):

The Launch image dimensions are indeed confusing, and require a lot of needless cross reference.  In Xcode there is a page where the launch images are drag and drop yet inexplicably lack pix dimensions!!

Through trial and error, Owen Rubin came up with the following dimensions and I made an image for your reference.  Please let me know if we've made any errors.

[image]

Comment: @Heitor, Fracdroid's answer doesn't work anymore on XCode 8.

Answer (score 34):

iOS Launch Image Sizes - (with newly added iPhone X) iPhone and iPad.

[image: iPhone X Launch Image Sizes (+ other sizes)]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you provide the original link?

Comment: oops, I don't have the original link.

Answer (score 29):

[image: iOS Launch Image Sizes - Xcode]

iOS Launch Image Sizes - Xcode iPhone/iPad

```
1x                = 320 x 480    
2x                = 640 x 960
Retina 4          = 640 x 1136
Retina HD 5.5     = 1242 x 2208
Retina HD 4.7     = 750 x 1334
Retina HD 5.5     = 2208 x 1242   (landscape)
iPad 1x           = 768 x 1024
iPad 2x           = 1536 x 2048
iPad 1x           = 1024 x 768    (landscape)
iPad 2x           = 2048 x 1536   (landscape)
```

Comment: but where is iphone landscape for 4.7 inch phone?

Answer (score 23):

In XCode select the slot for an image with the 'attributes inspector' tab open on the right hand side panel, it will tell you the Expected Size.

Comment: You are right. I clicked an empty image and I see its resolution in the property inspector as Expected Size. Thanks!

Comment: The listed "Static Launch Screen Images" in the latest HIG at https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/ do NOT actually agree with the "Expected Size" listed in Xcode under Attributes Inspector. E.g. for "iPhone Landscape iOS 8,9" expected is "2208 x 1242" but the HIG says 1920 x 1080. This is painful.

Comment: Xcode 8 lost its mind and no longer lists `Expected Size` for launch screen images when empty OR full launch image slots are selected. Verified as of Xcode 8.1.

Comment: @AlexZavatone: verified with xcode 8.2..not showing

Comment: @preetam Thanks.  I just checked with 8.2.1 earlier today.   Same thing.  Pure idiocy from Apple. TY.

Comment: Same its not showing in latest Xcode version 9.4.1 :(

Answer (score 11):

[user2339310](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2339310/user2339310)'s [link](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html) from [iPhone Development 101](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html) is a great source regarding the iOS launch image size(s). They have made a nice mockup with the specs:

[image: iPhone Development 101's Launch Sizes]

---

However, Apple has made it quite clear what sizes the launch image(s) should be:

[image: Apple's launch sizes]

[image: Arrow] [Click Me for high resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiwVV.png) [image: Arrow]

Taken from Apple's original page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: This image is out of date--it doesn't include any of the newer phone sizes/resolutions.

Answer (score 7):

I think both are working and it depends on wether you want the statusbar shown during launch or not.

Comment: Thanks, you're basically saying that I'm not forced to use one or the other, right?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Xcode 8.x** then Expected size will not be displayed in the attribute inspector.
You can see following sizes for reference for **Portrait** mode:

1X = 320 × 480

2X = 640 × 960

3X = 640 × 1136

5.5 = 1242 × 2208

4.7 = 750 × 1334

4 Ratina = 640 × 1136

Here are the dimensions with latest devices from [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)

[image: Here is the Image]

Comment: Xcode Version 8.2

iPhone Portrait iOS 8,9 = Retina HD 5.5(1242x2208) Retina HD 4.7(750x1334) 
iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9 = 2x(640x960) Retina 4(640x1136)
iPad Portrait iOS 7-9 = 1x(768x1024) 2x(1536x2048)

Answer (score 5):

also mentioned in design resources for iOS7

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1

Answer (score 4):

If you are showing status bar then use first one (20 pixel less height) else use second one (full size).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm confused since the ios human guidelines seem to imply that I should be showing the status bar.

Comment: You should use full size (1024x768px and 2048x1536px) images

Comment: 20 pixel less height . Good