# UIScreen bounds issue in ios 9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, uiscreen

So I'm having this app on the app store since 2010, and my initalization code since that time looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

   self.window.rootViewController = someViewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Now this worked until yesterday, but since I today updated to XCode 7 and iOS9, I'm having some issues. My app still launches in the simulator, but **no matter what iPhone device I pick**, I will get a window size of {320, 480}.

What is the proper way to do it?

[edit]
More details:

- everything was fine with XCode 6 / iOS 8
- see screenshot of how it looks now in iPhone 5S simulator. I get the same black back on the bottom of the view (my macbook screen wont fit the whole simulator window for a screenshot)
- as I see it, I dont have any launch image assigned at the moment. will this be the solution? if so, what size should I provide? do I need launch images for all iPhones? (4S, 5, 6, 6+)

[image]

Comment: You need to add support for larger devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus

Comment: It used to work fine with XCode 6 and iOS 8, the linked thread is about Xcode6?

Comment: Do you mean that the app used to get a larger window size on larger devices? If so, it’s weird that it would revert.

Comment: Correct, everything was fine in the simulators. I still have the compiled version on my iPhone 6 and its full screen.

Comment: Is the status bar larger than normal when you run it on your iPhone 6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91220/discussion-between-zev-eisenberg-and-user826955).

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue when rmaddy linked the other thread. I never used launch images, nor a launch storyboard, so this might be the reason why with iOS9 / XCode 7 it stopped working.
I still assemble the viewcontrollers programmatically, so it was sufficient to add blank launch images for all sizes. this site helped much to get the sizes right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832459/ios-launch-image-sizes

thanks everyone.