# How To set Launch Images for Universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, launch-screen, launchimage

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and my app is a universal app. I'm having a design issue when loading the launch images using the `assets` i.e. it showing some black screen background in `iPad Pro 11 inch` and `iPad pro 12.9 (3rd generation)` devices other than that it working fine in all devices. So how can solve that issue? And If I want to use the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file how can I set a single image to satisfy all screen sizes(which image size and what resolution(2x or 3x) have to use) ? or how to use the `Static Launch Screen Images` by the apple [click here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote there are two ways to configure the LaunchScreen:

- **Static image** from the special imagest - `LaunchImage.launchimage`
- **Designed screen** that can hold multiple UI elements - `LaunchScreen.storyboard`

If your launch screen is simple enough and you choose to use **Static image** please make sure that your Info.plist doesn't hold the following key: `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key> <string>LaunchScreen</string>`, if it does then the static image won't be used.
The `LaunchImage.launchimage` holds an image for all device types and tells you which image size to use.
If you use it and do populate all the images and still some devices has no launch image try cleaning and rebuilding your app and uninstalling and reinstalling the app from your test device or simulator. Also consider updating your environment (xCode).

If you choose to use **Designed screen** please avoid setting the source of your ImageView to the `LaunchImage.launchimage`, its a special imageset. You can only use regular `x.imagesets` with less images (1x 2x R4 3x).
Take a look at the [following answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53594432/1101710), it explains the mechanism that auto selects the image, it also has table that connects iPhone type to the selected image.